# Django model not persisting after save

Tags: django, save, models

I am setting a FK field and saving, but as you can see in the trace log the save doesn't seem to persist in the DB if I retrieve the object it's FK field returns to it's pre-saved value.

Model code

```
def do_transition(self, workflow_aware=None):
    ws = WorkflowState.objects.get(state=self.transition_to_state, workflow=workflow_aware.workflow)
    logging.debug("WorkflowState=%s" % ws)
    workflow_aware.current_state = ws
    workflow_aware.save()
    logging.debug(workflow_aware.current_state)
    activitycontent = workflow_aware.__class__.objects.get(pk=workflow_aware.pk)
    logging.debug(activitycontent.current_state)
```

Trace log

```
- DEBUG - WorkflowState=ActivityContent_Workflow_Submitted
- INFO - programcreator.base.models                   save() 
- INFO - programcreator.groupflow.models              save() 
- DEBUG - ActivityContent_Workflow_Submitted
- DEBUG - ActivityContent_Workflow_Draft
```

Comment: Fixed. A good question often answers itself. My super method was in the wrong conditional block :P

Comment: If you can post your answer and mark is as accepted it might help someone else with the same problem.